# CPanel integration with JetBrains PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I created an FTP Account on CPanel. I also tried to configure FTP on JetBrains PhpStorm, but I am not able to establish connection.

I made FTP Accounts as below;

```
FTP Username: ****@*********.org
FTP server: ****.****.org
FTP & explicit FTPS port:  21
```

I need suggestion on how to connect to `public_html/` folder from JetBrains PhpStorm and then synch files.

Comment: Try : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-a-remote-server-configuration.html

Answer (score 5):

Follow those steps:

1. Go to: File -> New Project from Existing Files...
2. Select: Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP/FTPS
3. Give a name and a path for the local copy of the project
4. Select: Add new remote server
5. Fill all the fields
6. Select as root folder the public_html folder

Comment: That connects me to the server but the public_html folder is not found

Comment: Try to look in `var/www` or in `/home/your_username`

Comment: Tried that but nothing displays there

Comment: Are you using the navigation PhpStorm's navigation menu?
It should looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/EMgEDjf.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

There is **no** reference in the previous answer on how to connect to cpanel instance, I had this issue too.

In PHPStorm's deployment menu there is a field to add the Host, now PHPStorm's connections have a prefixed `ftp://` (or `sftp`, depends what you choose).

Cpanel also has it's own stipulated connection method, it defaults to create your entry host as ftp.yoursite.com

PHPStorm interprets this as ftp://ftp.yoursite.com, thus you get an error.

This is what you should do to connect successfully:

- use SFTP
- write your host name as a top level domain (TLD) `yoursite.com`
- use port 22
- write root path with your user name:  `home/user-name`
- fill in your user name and then password

That worked for me.